# Optimization problem on 2-simplex

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have the following simple formulated optimization problem:

$$
f = \sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} \to \max \\
a + b+ c = 1
$$

In other words I want to maximize $f$ on simplex. How can I evaluate this?

Comment: Lagrange multipliers seem to work nicely.

Comment: Actually, that's not even necessary.  Note that symmetry tells you that $a=c$ at the extreme, so you can get down to a single variable.

Comment: @lulu thank you, but what do you mean by "symmetry tells" ? Do you mean that on the optimum $a = c$

Comment: Nothing in the problem distinguishes $a$ from $c$, so we'll have $a=c$ at the extreme.  Should say, if you aren't comfortable reasoning that way (and it can lead one astray at times), use Lagrange.  It's easy and the desired symmetry drops out of that instantly.

Comment: @lulu thank you again

Answer (score 3):

By the AM-GM inequality

$$\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{(2a)b}+\sqrt{b(2c)}\right)\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{2a+b}{2}+\frac{b+2c}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Equality holds when $2a=b=2c$ and then $(a,b,c)=(\frac14,\frac12,\frac14)$.